# refactor method in ruby instead 3 calls to DB make it one call

Tags: ruby

```
def post_stat
    @urls = CallUrl.all
    call = params[:call_url_id] ? params[:call_url_id] : CallUrl.first.id
    call_url = CallUrl.find(call)
    @Posts = callback_url.posts
end
```

I am trying to refactor this code to make only one call to database insted of 3 times in each class I am calling?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is Rails, though that is not specified. Your `@urls` instance variable isn't used in the method, though I don't know if it's used later on in the view. I'll leave it out for this answer.

You can do this with only one database trip, so long as params[:call_url_id] contains a value:

```
@posts = Post.where(call_url_id: params[:call_url_id])
```

But this doesn't address your fallback position, which is to get all posts belonging to the first CallUrl. There's no way to know what posts are related to that first CallUrl without making an extra trip to the database to get its id. But we can optimize so that the extra trip is made only when params[:call_url_id] is not provided:

```
def post_stat
  call_url_id = params[:call_url_id].presence || CallUrl.first.id
  @posts = Post.where(call_url_id: call_url_id)
end
```